# Changing stored procedure so that it will work with Local connection to SQL Server Db (and update a table)

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, visual-studio-2017, sqlconnection

I have the following code and Insert-statement.. and connection.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
con.ConnectionString = ("Data Source=DESKTOP-PGHMM6M;Initial Catalog=LocalUsers;Integrated Security=True");
con.Open();

string st = "INSERT INTO data(Username, Password, Hash, EncryptedPassword) VALUES (@Username, @Password, @Hash, @EncryptedPassword)";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(st, con);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", Username);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", textBox2.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Hash", savedPasswordHash);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EncryptedPassword", FinalEncryptedPass);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();   // invalid object name 'data' < where is this object? 
con.Close();
```

When I run the program it returns the following error:

> Invalid object name 'data'

I'm not sure what I did to create this situation. I was fulling around with the "stand-alone sql features" in Visual studio 2017, and I'm not sure where to start, to get back on track to use a local SQL Management Server Studio db that I created.

I found a previous question with the following::

1. Right click the database project --> Properties
2. Click Debug
3. Under Target Connection String, click Edit and select the correct database server
4. Create a new stored procedure

But I'm not sure what any of this is referring to ^.. any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

welcome to stackoverflow.com

it says you do not have a table (in which you are inserting data) name : "data"...
 
you must have a database name "LocalUsers". in this database,
 
create a table name : "data" (with given fields) and you are good to go.